# use HTML5 and CSS to create 5 equal and elastic columns that adjust height in a single row

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm fairly beginner with CSS and wish to make a HTML block from scratch on our Jive platform that is a single row of 5 buttons.  Each button will contain an icon and text with the entire button being a link.
I want the block to span 100% of the div it is in, and the buttons to adjust height and width depending on page width so that all 5 buttons are always on the same row until the screen width drops to below 600px and each button will fill a row each.

So far I have:

```css
#newsnav-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: beige;
}
#newsnav-container a {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*display:inline-block;
     height:100%;
     width:23%;
     margin:0 2% 0 0;*/
  background-color: #96C;
}
#newsnav-container a > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  background-color: #96C;
  float: left;
  width: 18.16%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #newsnav-container a > div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  < <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="newsnav-container">
    <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link1">
      <div><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>1</span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link2">
      <div><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>2</span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link3">
      <div><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>3</span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link4">
      <div><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>4</span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link5">
      <div><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>5</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem I have at the moment and can't get past is the 5th button won't stay up in the row with the others if the window is any smaller than full-screen on my 1920 res.

[image]

How do I fix this?

(Please excuse my lack of formatting and content - like I said I'm building from scratch and am using block colours to get my elements' responsiveness right first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method #01 (Preferred):**

Use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
#newsnav-container {
    display: flex;
}
#newsnav-container a {
    width: 19%;
}
```

```css
#newsnav-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: beige;
  display: flex;
}

#newsnav-container a {
  margin-right: 1%;
  width: 19%;
}
#newsnav-container a > div {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #96C;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #newsnav-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #newsnav-container a {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="newsnav-container">
  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link1">
    <div><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>1</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link2">
    <div><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>2</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link3">
    <div><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>3</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link4">
    <div><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>4</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link5">
    <div><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>5</span></div>
  </a>         
</div>
```

**Method #02:**

Use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` propreties.

```
#newsnav-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#newsnav-container a {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```css
#newsnav-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: beige;
}

#newsnav-container a {
  display: table-cell;
}
#newsnav-container a > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin:0 5px 0 0;
  background-color:#96C;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #newsnav-container {
    display: block;
  }
  #newsnav-container a {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="newsnav-container">
  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link1">
    <div><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>1</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link2">
    <div><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>2</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link3">
    <div><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>3</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link4">
    <div><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>4</span></div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link5">
    <div><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>5</span></div>
  </a>         
</div>
```

Comment: That does it, maybe change `width` from `20%` to `19%` and add `margin: 0 .5%` to `#newsnav-container a` selector to keep the margins between the links.

Comment: @EaziLuizi Ok thanks for your suggestion, I've reflected this change in my answer.

Comment: Sweet, good quick answer, beat me, so thought I would just add my 2 cents :)

Comment: In your snippet you have left my `display: block;`... should this be removed when using flex?

Comment: @ReeceDodds yes it should be removed.

Comment: Cheers!  Can I use something like `#newsnav-container a:last-child {
 margin-right:0;}` to get rid of the margin on the last button and only have a margin between them?

Comment: @ReeceDodds yes you can but remember to increase `width` from `19% `to `20%` for last child as well when you remove `margin`.

Comment: I see.  I've decided to use `#newsnav-container a {margin:0 0.25% 0 0.25%; width:19.5%;}` instead because each of the buttons will be center aligned anyway.
Thanks again to you all for your help and comments.

Comment: Thanks again Muhammad.  My finished product is pretty much along the lines of this http://codepen.io/whitenoise83/pen/bBGwyy

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this. One is with floating the parent `a` and making its box-sizing as border-box. The `border-box` property will count padding and border in its width.

Another way can be with display as `table-cell`

```css
#newsnav-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: beige;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#newsnav-container a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
#newsnav-container a > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  background-color: #96C;
}
#newsnav-container a:last-child > div {
  margin-right: 0
}
/*
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #newsnav-container a > div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="newsnav-container">
  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link1">
    <div><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>1</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link2">
    <div><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>2</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link3">
    <div><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>3</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link4">
    <div><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>4</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link5">
    <div><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>5</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is using **CSS Flexbox**.

Apply `display: flex;` property to `#newsnav-container` and give `flex: 1;` to its childrens i.e. `#newsnav-container a`. Have a look at the code below for proper understanding.

```css
#newsnav-container {
    display: flex;
}

#newsnav-container a {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1;
    background-color:#96C;
}
#newsnav-container a > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin:0 5px 0 0;
  background-color:#96C;
  float: left;
  width: 18.16%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #newsnav-container a > div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
  
<body>
    <div id="newsnav-container">
        <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link1">
            <div><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>1</span></div>
        </a>

        <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link2">
            <div><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>2</span></div>
        </a>

        <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link3">
            <div><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>3</span></div>
        </a>

        <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link4">
            <div><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>4</span></div>
        </a>

        <a class="link-button2" target="_parent" href="link5">
            <div><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>5</span></div>
        </a>         
    </div>
</body>
```

Learn more about **[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

Hope this helps!